# Stream of classes using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

I want to create and return a stream of objects using method refernece, but it is not working for me. This is the example I am trying where Promotion is an interface, which is implemented by BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl.

```
//This is not working
public Stream<Promotion> getPromotionList() {
    return Stream.of(BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl::new);
}

//This is working
public Stream<Promotion> getPromotionList() {
   return Stream.of(new BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl());
}
```

I can guess method reference needs to be a functional interface, which my promotions objects are.

Comment: "but it is not working for me" is not proper problem description. Please post error message you are getting so others facing same error would be able to find your question and potential answers. Also describe why do you think it should work.

Comment: BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl::new is a constructor reference. It can be used to implement a Supplier<Promotion>, but not a Promotion. Stream.of() expects a Promotion, not a Supplier.

Comment: `return Stream.of(((Supplier<Promotion>)BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl::new).get());` will work.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I was not sure, constructor reference returns a supplier rather than that object itself.

Comment: It does not return a Supplier. It's a lambda, whose type depends on the context. If you assign it to a Supplier variable or argument, it will be a Supplier. But it could be an instance of any functional interface that has a compatible signature.

Answer (score 3):

If `Promotion` is a functional interface, and `BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl` is a class implementing `Promotion`, then `BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl::new` is like a lambda that returns another lambda.  You don't want that; you just want `new BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl()`.

`new BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl()` and `BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl::new` are *completely different.*  The first one just creates a new `BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl`.  The second one is a lambda that, when called, generates a new `BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl`.

Comment: I don't want a new instance at this point of time, rather I want a lambda expression, which will create a new instance when it will be evaluated.

Comment: @krmanish007 Then it sounds like you don't want a `Stream<Promotion>`, but rather a `Stream<Supplier<Promotion>>`.

Comment: I got my answer from JB Nizet's comment,

Comment: Or perhaps if you want an infinite `Stream` of freshly generated `Promotion`s, you want `Stream.generate(BuyTwoGetThreePromotionImpl::new)`.  But your question doesn't make that clear.

Comment: thats also a g8 suggestion, its worth trying. I will learn more about this method, to see how it behave. Many Thanks Louis.